# Which operator to overload in order to use my class in an if-statement?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, overwrite

For example, I have defined a class

```
class MyClass
{
   ....
};
```

which operator do I have to overload in order to do the if comparison with a `MyClass` object?

eg:

```
MyClass cc;
if ( cc ) // compile error
{
   //do some stuff
}
```

I tried with

```
 bool operator == ( int value ) ; //guess the if () will call this
```

or

```
 bool operator != ( int value ) ;
```

but both give me a compile error!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: In the presence of C++11 the answer for such a question will look differently (now explicit operator bool is recommended instead of safe bool idiom). I am not sure how SO handles such change of information over time...

Comment: There's no comparison in your example. If you want an implicit conversion to `bool`, define `operator bool()`. By the way you never overwrite an operator. You either override or overload one. These terms have different meaning.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, it is pointed out in a comment under David Rodriguez's answer. That should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

You should provide a `bool` conversion operator:

```
struct MyClass
{
  explicit operator bool() const { return true; }   
};
```

Here, an `explicit` operator is used to prevent unwanted implicit conversions to other types, specifically numeric types. Note that this is only possible since C++11.

Comment: `explicit`? Are you sure about this one?

Comment: @bash.d Yes, `explicit` is correct here. `if` expressions are "contextually converted to bool", for which an explicit operator can be used. And it prevents all the mess of implicit conversion.

Comment: @Angew awesome! Didn't know this one... Do you find it in Stroustrup's book somehwere?

Comment: @bash.d: In C++11, yes; it prevents unwanted conversions to arbitrary numeric types, while allowing the `if` test in the question. In historic versions of the language, either drop the `explicit` and live with the danger, or use the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

Comment: @bash.d No idea, never read it. I've read the standard, though; I have it from there.

Comment: @bash.d it is C++11, so it will be in the next edition of the C++ language book.

Comment: Isn't an implicit conversion exactly what is desired in the example given in the question?

Comment: @MarkRansom: There's a special exception to allow an `explicit` conversion operator to be used in an `if` (or similar) statement.

Comment: Note that in C++03, this is highly unrecommended. Without the `explicit`, the use of a conversion to `bool` will trigger in many contexts where you don't want it to.

Answer (score 4):

`operator bool()` is the one you want. It takes care of type conversion from your class to type `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide a conversion operator for `bool` or for something convertible to `bool`. If you have C++11, the best way is this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  explicit operator bool () const {
    ...
  }
};
```

If you don't have C++11 (or at least its support for explicit conversion operators), things get a bit more tricky (because an implicit conversion can kick you real painfully when you least expect it). See the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) for more information on this.

Comment: I was unaware that C++11 added a new usage for the `explicit` keyword.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, it did, you can now have explicit conversion operators too, not just constructors. Very useful, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You could override `operator bool()`, but according to your example, you might also consider creating simple method that will return `bool`. Then its usage could for example look like this:

```
MyClass cc;
if (cc.isValid())
{
   // do some stuff
}
```

which would be more straightforward and also easier to read in this case. Custom operators are great for many things, but don't force it. Sometimes it's better to just ***[keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)*** :)